# Single-Select and Multi-Select controls in Ant Design Mobile

Tags: mobile, antd, antd-mobile

I am trying to determine what are the Single-Select and Multi-Select controls in Ant Design Mobile.

1. As far as I can tell, the [Picker](https://mobile.ant.design/components/picker/) is the single select control. Is this correct?
2. Is there a multi-select control?
3. The controls don't seem to work on a desktop, e.g. I am not able to use my mouse to change the selection. Is this intended?